# Why does cURL in PHP print to the Terminal?

Tags: php, curl, terminal

I have a PHP script which is called in the Ubuntu Terminal, not from a browser. That PHP script does some cURL calls. This prints a lot of stuff (request and response headers for each cURL request) to the Terminal. I'm not complaining (in fact, it can be useful to see what the script is doing), but I am confused. There are no `print_r` calls or anything similar, so I don't know where this output is coming from. What causes it? Is it some side effect of the cURL library itself?

Comment: What curl opts are you setting in the PHP script?

Comment: The PHP manual really is [far more useful than most people give it credit for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php). Your question is covered by the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Set this option before you execute.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php)

> **TRUE** to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of *outputting it directly*.